# Why function() is not called in ad so ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I have to call to my spring controller through ajax but when the page is launching and when i click **ADD** it's not doing anything.

```js
function myFunction(x,y){
     var num1= x;
     var num2= y;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: operation.htm,
         success: function(response){
             //what i will do with the viewname here? how to display the page
             $("#content").html(response);
         },
         error: function(e){
             alert("Error"+e)
         }
     });
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="javascript:myFunction(150,200);">ADD</a>
 <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not showing anything when clicking

Comment: have you included the script for jquery in your html?

Comment: yes **<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>**

Comment: **it's not doing anything** explain it more, this is not enough information. Did you check what are you getting in console logs? Did you try to debug?

Comment: It's not calling the function() when i tried **console.log()**  before function it's displaying but after function one is not displaying even after clicking the link